# index.php vs index.html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am not understanding when my main website page should be `index.php` and not `index.html` and what's the difference between the two.

And in case if it's `index.php`, how to manage with the javascipt code.

Thank you.

Comment: `index.php` is exactly the same as `index.html` with one exception - `index.php` can also run php code *(which is placed between `<?php` and `?>` tags)*. There are some useful little things that PHP can do, such as using `include()` functions, that almost anyone could use, whether they connect to a database or not. Bottom line: they are virtually the same. Use whichever one you wish.

Answer (score 0):

> my main website page should be index.php and not index.html

In a simple web server configuration, if you request a URL which maps onto a directory, then the server will look inside that for an index document.

It will do this by comparing the files in the directory to a list of possible index document names which often include `index.html` and `index.php`.

It checks them in the order of its list and stops when it finds a match.

---

Adjacent to this, such servers are typically configured to serve `.html` files as static files and to execute `.php` files as PHP and serve the result.

---

> And in case if it's index.php how to manage with the javascipt code.

Generating HTML from PHP instead of a static file has absolutely no bearing on how client-side JavaScript is managed.

If you're talking about server-side JS, then you probably don't want to be using PHP at all.

Answer (score 0):

`index.extension` is the main trigger file which can be .html, .php or other extensions.

in case of server end programming or you are using PHP language then trigger file should be `index.php` while for only html content you can go with `index.html`

Regarding, adding javascript in index.php file, it could be like

```
<?php 
  echo "I am here in PHP code";
  ?>
  <script>
    alert("I am here in javascript");
    console.log("here in console");
  </script>
  <?php
  echo "I am here ending code";
?>
```